# Terraform: how to run multiple actions on same resource during deployment?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

This question is related to deploying resources on Azure using provider version 2.99.

I'm trying to:

1. deploy a resource (e.g. key vault, azurerm_key_vault)
2. populate this resource (e.g. secrets, azurerm_key_vault_secret)
3. change the deployed resource (e.g. activate firewall, azurerm_key_vault)

Something like this:

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault" "kv" {
 # create key vault
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "kv-secret-01" {
 # create first secret
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "kv-secret-02" {
 # create second secret
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault" "kv" {
 # enable firewall on deployed kv
}
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: That is not how terraform works. You have a description of resources and terraform tries to make the resources look like what you describe them to be. If you have two different descriptions of the same object terraform does not know what to do. You need to merge the two declarations into one. Why do you think you need two resource declarations?

Comment: The reason is that azurerm_key_vault_secret does not succeed if the azurerm_key_vault resource is deployed with either firewall or specific access policies enabled. The objective is to deploy a fully configured (security-wise) and populated vault. Did not want to add the terraform user or source IP in the TF code, but will appreciate other approaches on how to do this. Besides: how do people populate a vault that is already locked (firewall + access policies) with TF, will this require two distinct executions?
Note: same issue happens with storage accounts with firewall enabled.

Comment: yeah you can't use terraform like that. Either you need to use some az CLI around it to open and close the firewall (in case the resource already exists) or you need to insert the build agent IP address into the tf deployment and whitelist it as part of it

Comment: **Hey @!, I did reproduce this issue and the solution worked for me; do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tested in my Environment was getting the below error while creating `Key Vault Secret` as my `IP Address` is not lised allowed ip addresses in `network_acls`.**

[image]

[image]

**If you Requirement is Deploy a Keyvault with either firewall or specific access policies enabled (Allowed to access KeyVault with Specific IP address only, You need to add the Ip address, As i have added above Ip address in terrform code from where i am accessing, you can use the below terraform code)**

***main.tf***

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "2.99"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}


data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {
    
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "v-XXXX-xXXXtree"
  #location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault" "example" {
  name                       = "TestKeyVault3246"
  location                   = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name        = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  tenant_id                  = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  sku_name                   = "premium"
  soft_delete_retention_days = 7

  access_policy {
    tenant_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
    object_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id

    key_permissions = [
      "create",
      "get",
    ]

    secret_permissions = [
      "set",
      "get",
      "delete",
      "purge",
      "recover"
    ]
  }
    network_acls {
    # The Default Action to use when no rules match from ip_rules / 
    # virtual_network_subnet_ids. Possible values are Allow and Deny
    default_action = "Deny"

    # Allows all azure services to acces your keyvault. Can be set to 'None'
    bypass         = "AzureServices"

    # The list of allowed ip addresses.
    ip_rules       = ["1.1.1.1","2.2.2.2","115.187.40.49"]

  }
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "example" {
  count = length(var.key_vault_Secret_Value)
  name         = "TestKeyVaultSecret-${count.index}"
  value        = var.key_vault_Secret_Value[count.index]
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.example.id
}
```

***variable.tf***

```
variable "key_vault_Secret_Value" {
  type        = list(string)
  default     = ["szechuan", "szechuan1"]
}
```

[image]

---

> Did not want to add the terraform user or source IP in the TF code,
> but will appreciate other approaches on how to do this. Besides: how
> do people populate a vault that is already locked (firewall + access
> policies) with TF.

If you have the Key Vault firewall enabled then any machine that needs to talk to it will need to be allowed in that firewall, it would be a pretty terrible firewall if that was not the case. There are a few ways you can work with this:

- Add your machines IP into the firewall permanently, maybe as part of your Terraform deployment
- Run your Terraform Pipelines from another machine, like a build agent, and allow this IP. Moving to using CI/CD tools for your Terraform is going to be beneficial in may other ways too
- **As above, use a build agent, but instead of using adding it's external IP to the KV firewall, use private endpoints to allow access over the private network. This requires the machine to be in Azure, or connected to Azure over VPN/ExpressRoute**

***Reference : https://serverfault.com/questions/1086356/is-it-possible-to-use-terraform-and-an-azure-key-vault-firewall-without-having-t***